# Strange behaviour on mouseover for search button

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I am currently putting together a website for a friend.

It is working ok except the search box.

If you can see at http://wordpress.alternet.com.au/ there is a search box at the top right of the window.  The search icon/image is positioned where it needs to be.

I am using Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m and when I mouse over the menu items at the top of the page, the search icon/image repositions itself to the left of the search area.

I can't figure out why this is happening?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your classes in style.css  with this update. 
100% it's working all the day `=D`

```
 form#searchform input[type="text"] {
       height: 28px;
 }
 form#searchform {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, can you enlighten me as to why it was behaving like that?

Answer (score 0):

............. Hi now add to `box-sizing` in your `input` or `focus` as like this

**Add** `this css` in your `stylesheet`

```
form#searchform input[type="text"], form#searchform input[type="text"]:focus{
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer, but for your information, this is how it looks in FireFox:

[image: looks broken]

Comment: The smaller search box is from the box-border changes

Comment: you can solve it by setting the height equal to the height of the submit button

Comment: Thanks Mark, it was fine before I made some changes recommended in another answer. I backed those changes out and the height is not the problem anymore. @alnassre provided the solution to my original issue.